# How to give Azure Devops REST API access to an external organizaton without impersonating a user (PAT, etc)

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to set up an extension that sets up webhooks on an Azure Devops project, and then do processing in my backend services when I receive one of these webhook events. The problem is, once I receive the event I don't have access to the Azure Devops REST api in order to do things like look at  pull request, write a comment, etc.

I don't want to use something that will make me impersonate a user, as this would result in any comments my services make look like they were authored by that user. Instead, I want to have some token, etc. that I can use to make those api calls as an external/third party service.

I looked at service principals, but after a few hours of reading docs, creating and registering my app, and creating a service connection, I don't think that it would let me get access to a different (not owned by me) Azure Devops organization's resources. (Admittedly I am just starting to get into Azure, so maybe I am wrong and if so I'd love to hear about how to do this).

Comment: Your extension is installed into an Azure DevOps organization, it calls a service that is external to the organization, and in that service, you want to call the REST API of the organization that the extension is installed into, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My extension is installed into some Azure DevOps organization, it defines webhooks that call my backend service, and in that backend service I want to call the REST API of that organization without impersonating a user.

Comment: You could create an Azure DevOps user account that is specifically for the service to use for the API calls. I have seen two-way integrations that depend on web hooks and a service user. (If this is going to be a publicly offered extension, it will raise security concerns.)

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, the intent is for it to be a public extension. I don't really want to be creating users in all of these DevOps organizations. Even if I did that, I think that would mean my extension would need some admin privileges to create said user right? Which like you said would be a security concern.

Comment: Right. You don't want to be creating a user account (or a service principal or a managed identity). And you don't want to use the user account directly. You would want your service to be given a scoped PAT. PATs expire and need to be periodically renewed. An admin on the host organization would need to create and renew the PAT. You wouldn't be able to make your extension 'turn key' or 'zero configuration' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to use something that will make me impersonate a user, as this would result in any comments my services make look like they were authored by that user. Instead, I want to have some token, etc. that I can use to make those api calls as an external/third party service.

I'm afraid it's not supported.

To use the rest api call, you can check the [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2#authenticate) method listed. To write a pull request comment, the token need to be authorized by the organization, could not be from external/third party.

Although there is [OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) method which can create access token for rest api, on behalf of user, the token could also expire.